# Disable Elysia Cron task programmatically

Tags: cron

I have a custom module where I create several cron tasks using HOOK_cronapi.
This is done when the user visits a page and has a form to create those tasks.

I also need that the user can disable those tasks but I can't find anything in the elysia cron documentation on how to disable a cron job.

After it is created I can't disable it programmatically? (I can do it via GUI)

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `if (variable_get('some_var', FALSE)) { ...` in `hook_cronapi()`?

Comment: Nice idea Clive. I think that may solve my problem. Anyway, there should be an option to enable/disable the task.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an option for one per task, but you could create a channel just for those jobs, and then disable the channel (which there is an option for)

Comment: Clive, do you know how can I enable/disable the channel in my module? I don't see that option either.

Comment: `elysia_cron_set_channel_disabled('channel_name', TRUE);` should do it (or `FALSE` to enable)

Comment: That is not working. In fact, I can't even know which channel my task is running and changing in the GUI doesnt't change anything also. The manual and API docs don't help a lot either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this is pretty old but if you are only concerned with one task and not a whole channel...

```
elysia_cron_set_job_disabled('mymodule_cron', true);
```

will disable a cron job. Not surprisingly,

```
elysia_cron_set_job_disabled('mymodule_cron', false);
```

enables it again.